# Any alternatives applications to run cordova apps similar to what Phonegap Developer App provides for phonegap applications

Tags: cordova

I recently discovered of this New **[Phonegap Developer App](http://app.phonegap.com/)** that lets you wirelessly run your phongap applications without need of going through the build hassle and test your app as in native app running in your mobile phone.

It also supports live refresh and you need not refresh or deploy app again while you are making any changes. Also you can access and test all the native features. THIS IS A HUGE PLUS !!

But the issue is this feature only runs for Phonegap apps and not cordova apps (or maybe they are and i haven't found a way yet).

So i just wanted to know if there is a way to use the said features that above app provides with cordova applications ?

Answer (score 0):

You could install phonegap as well, then use the feature. You may get a result by just doing a "phonegap serve" in your app folder. If not then you can simply create a new app using phonegap and set up a batch file to copy the contents of your cordova's www folder and serve it, e.g.

```
@echo off
xcopy \foo\cordovaapp\www\*.* \foo\phonegapapp\www /s/y
cd \foo\phonegapapp
phonegap serve
```

Comment: Thanks @TrevorBest for the inputs...i copied my cordova's www folder and copied them into phonegap's www folder. I managed to open the app successfully but now there is an issue regarding plugins...will i need to install all those plugins for phonegap app again although i had them installed in cordova app ?

Comment: Yes, you should install the plugins in the new folder as well

Answer (score 0):

We recently announced a product that goes beyond Phone Gap Build in some regards: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/phonegap-cordova-compatibility-for-codename-one.html

We compare this in the post but the big benefits are:

- Build Cloud On Steroids
- Better Native Code Support
- Better Protection Of IP
- IDE Integration Java - JavaScript - HTML
- Easy, Doesn't Require A Mac, Automates Certificates/Signing
- Migration To Java